# Getting error (pdf inclusion): reading image failed in Lualatex for some PDF documents and not others

Tags: pdftex, luatex

I have moved over from pdflatex to lualatex and in the process, it seems like I am only able to embed some pdf documents and not others.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multido}

\newcommand{\allgraphic}[1]{
\begin{center}
    \saveimageresource{#1}
    \multido{\i=1+1}{\the\lastsavedimageresourcepages}{
    \includegraphics[page=\i,width=0.48\textwidth]{#1}
    }
\end{center}
}

\begin{document}
  \allgraphic{non-working.pdf}
\end{document}
```

I am not sure if I am missing something.

Comment: preflight says that your pdf has syntax errors.

Comment: I am not seeing any in Overleaf

Comment: overleaf won't look _inside_ the PDF you are using. Ulrike used a PDF checking tool on it.

Comment: Is the error your seeing this 7.1: Error on MetaData, Failed to instanciate property in xmp:CreateDate

Comment: It looks like that was the issue. I removed all the metadata from the document and it worked. Is there a way round in latex, or do I have to clear the metadata of all the documents that I use?